# get_dir_file_info() hangs when run on a large directory

Tags: codeigniter

I have made a little function that deletes files based on date.  Prior to doing the deletions, it lets the user choose how many days/months back to delete files, telling them how many files and how much memory it would clean up.

It worked great in my test environment, but when I attempted to test it on a larger directory (approximately 100K files), it hangs.

I’ve stripped everything else from my code to ensure that it is the get_dir_info() function that is causing the issue.

```
$this->load->helper('file');
$folder = "iPad/images/";
set_time_limit (0);
echo "working<br />";
$dirListArray = get_dir_file_info($folder);
echo "still working";
```

When I run this, the page loads for approximately 60 seconds, then displays only the first message “working” and not the following message “still working”.

It doesn’t seem to be a system/php memory problem as it is coming back after 60 seconds and the server respects my set_time_limit() as I’ve had to use that for other processes.

Is there some other memory/time limit I might be hitting that I need to adjust?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the [CI user guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/file_helper.html) the `get_dir_file_info()` is:

> Reads the specified directory and builds an array containing the filenames, filesize, dates, and permissions. Sub-folders contained within the specified path are only read if forced by sending the second parameter, $top_level_only to FALSE, as this can be an intensive operation.

so if you are saying that you have 100k files then the best way to do it, is to cut it into two steps:
**First:** use `get_filenames('path/to/directory/')` to retrieve all your files without their information.
**Second:** use `get_file_info('path/to/file', $file_information)` to retrieve a specific file info, as you might not need all the file information immediately. it can be done on file name click or something relevant.

the idea here is not to force your server to deal with large amount of process while in production. that would kill two things, [responsiveness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsiveness), and [performance](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/performance) (I haven't found a better definition for performance) but the idea here is clear.